# Flexbox: How do I create my thumbnails to span 100% of the container width?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am attempting to create equal divs that span 100% of their containing element.

You can view the Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/rq1vkdcg/7/). How must the code be written to span the divs from side - side of the container?

**html**

```
<div class="container">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    width: 100%;
    background: blue;
}
.container div {
    width: 24%;
    height: 2.5em;
    background-color: red;
    margin-right: 1%;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Essentially, I am trying to replicate something similar to this:

[image]

Comment: You want a full-width container with each child div spanning to 25% of it's parent container or 100% for each div? In the above screenshot, the divs are not spanning 25% or 100% though as 25% means 4 divs per row and 100% means 1 div per row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `n` elements per row, there are `n-1` gaps.
If you want a 1% wide gap, that means the divs can occupy 97% of the width for 4 elements per row.

So you need to set the width to 97/4 = 24.25%
And cancel out the margin every 4th child.

```
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    width: 100%;
    background: blue;
}
.container div {
    width: 24.25%;
    height: 2.5em;
    background-color: red;
    margin-right: 1%;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container div:nth-child(4n) {
    margin-right:0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rq1vkdcg/10/